# How to display multiples images from MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to know how to display multiples images from MySQL in Html.

I have two files:
photogallery.php where I display the image and gallery.php where I have the php code. 
This works but I can only display 1 image and I can't see all images!

Here is the code for photogallery.php where I display the photo:

```
<div align='left'>
    <img src='gallery.php' height='95' width='95'/>
</div>
```

and here is the code for gallery.php:

```
session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "photos";
$tbl_name="gallery";


mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password")or die ("error22");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("error2");

$ussername=$_SESSION['username'];

$query=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where username='$ussername'");

while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

     $imageData=$row["image"];
     //header("content-type:image/jpeg");
     echo $imageData;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're echoing `$imageData` to single `src` attribute. You should do `while` loop in your `photogallery.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have image data stored on the database with a function like get_file_contents :

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

     $imageData=$row["image"];

     echo "<div align='left'>";
     echo "  <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," 
          . base64_encode($imageData) . "' height='95' width='95'/>";
     echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if we assume that `$row["image"]` is path to image, then you should change your code like below:

```
...
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

     $imageData=$row["image"];
     ?>
       <div align='left'>
          <img src='<?php echo $imageData;?>' height='95' width='95'/>
       </div>
     <?php
}
...
```

I don't execute my code, I want show you only idea